# Are there other ways to get an object property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a `dataLayer` array that has objects inside it:

```
dataLayer[3]
Object {event: "gerar-evento", event-category: "Chat", event-acion: "Vendas", event-label: "Pré Fixo 15"}
```

When I try to select a property of this object I get an error

If I try:

```
dataLayer[3].event
```

It works fine, returning `gerar-evento`, but if I try:

```
dataLayer[3].event-label
```

I get this error: `ReferenceError: label is not defined`

Is there another way to select a property from an object? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) since `event-label` is not a valid identifier

```
dataLayer[3]['event-label']
```

Comment: In case it's not clear why `event-label` isn't a valid identifier:  it's an expression that subtracts a variable called `label` from one called `event`.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript you have two ways to get object properties:

1. Dot notation: `object.property`
2. Bracket notation: `object['property-with-dash']` which is the one you have to use in your case:

   dataLayer[3]['event-category']

Also with the bracket notation, you can use variables to get properties out of the object, for example:

```
 var eventName = 'event-category';
 dataLayer[3][eventName]
```

would give you the same result.